# Почему мой сайт на GitHub не грузится полностью?

Tags: html, css, github

Недавно сверстал сайт портфолио и залил его на GitHub. Но как оказалось он полностью не грузится. Открывается только пустая страница с загаловками. В чём причина понять не могу! Я новичок, может где что напутал? Сылка: [шаблон сайта](https://sergey-max-vin.github.io/Freelancer-portfolio/)

Comment: некорреткные пути до картинок....попробуй сделать относительные.... т.е. без слэша в начале

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Не очень получается!

Comment: Там изменения  не сразу вступают в силу. + попробуй кэш браузера почистить

Comment: у тебя такая же проблема с main.js и hero.png.  Осталось только их починить  ....  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVXW5.png

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, чего там чистить нужно? Исправить путь картинок?    if (nav.classList.toggle('open')) {
    navBtnImg.src = "/image/icons/nav-close.svg";
    } else {
        navBtnImg.src = "/image/icons/nav-open.svg";
    }

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137498/discussion-between-sergey-from-khabarovsk-and--).

Comment: Алексей, все заработало! Огромное спасибо!)) <script src="./js/main.js"></script> Тут точку тоже надо было поставить!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в путях для картинок, попробуйте поставить точку перед слешем, чтобы получился путь "./image/...."

Comment: Не работает! вот ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/sergey-max-vin/Freelancer-portfolio

Comment: Все работает, учтите что после обновления репозитория нужно подождать минут 10, github не сразу обновляет

Comment: Спасибо большое за помошь! Я вас понял!